# I can not connect my Mbed Simulator to my TTN end device, I am using docker

Tags: docker, iot, simulator, mbed

I am trying to connect my Mbed Simulator to my applications end device on The Things Network. I am using the LoRaWaN simulator and entered the correct EUI's applicable.

[Proof of EUI id applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq9KO.png)

When I try to run the simulator, I never seem to get a connection to my TTN device. All it says is

> Connection - In Progress ...

and there is no response at my end device feed either. However, my friends can connect to my end device fine with the same EUI's needed. So it is most likely a fault at my end and not any wrong configurations at TTN.

I am using Ubuntu to run the container on my docker. However, I am very new to this so I don't understand much. My docker is changed so it accepts my wsl 2 distros.

[wsl 2 ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWJIz.png)

This is a schools project so I need to find a solution for this to work. This is my first entry and I hope I've explained everything well.

Edit:
This is the error that is thrown in the console

> Uncaught RuntimeError: float unrepresentable in integer range
> at __ZN16SX1276_LoRaRadio11time_on_airE10modem_typeh (SX1276_LoRaRadio.cpp:539)
> at __ZN16SX1276_LoRaRadio8transmitEj (SX1276_LoRaRadio.cpp:905)
> at __ZN16SX1276_LoRaRadio4sendEPhh (SX1276_LoRaRadio.cpp:568)
> at __ZN7LoRaPHY11handle_sendEPhh (LoRaPHY.cpp:118)
> at __ZN7LoRaMac11schedule_txEv (LoRaMac.cpp:1744)
> at __ZN7LoRaMac23on_backoff_timer_expiryEv (LoRaMac.cpp:882)
> at __ZN4mbed8CallbackIFvvEE13function_callINS2_14method_contextI7LoRaMacMS5_FvvEEEEEvPKv (Callback.h:677)
> at __ZN6events10EventQueue13function_callIN4mbed8CallbackIFvvEEEEEvPv (Callback.h:569)
> at _equeue_dispatch__async_cb_479 (equeue.c:427)
> at dynCall_vi (equeue.c:491)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Without sharing any code, it's pretty difficult to provide help

Comment: I've tried restarting my computer, I've tried creating a new end device on my application on TTN, however as explained my deviced on TTN is not the issue. I've tried restarting and also deleting and creating a new container for my docker, however the issue remains. The code is presented in the pictures through the hyperlinks. I am stuck at trying to get a connection from my Mbed simulator to my TTN applications device.

Comment: The simulator is not my code either, it is already a finished piece of code